# Formatting output in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have following predicate

```
 sqrt_table(X,Y,Result):-
    X=:=Y,
    Z is sqrt(X),
    Result = [[X,Z]].
 sqrt_table(X,Y,Result):-
    X>Y,
    Q is X-1,
    sqrt_table(Q,Y,Z),
    T is sqrt(X),
    append([[X,T]],Z,Result).
```

When I use it, it outputs me a round number, ie. 2,3,4,5,6, instead of floats. How to format it to output float result?

Comment: Can you show what query you entered? When I ran your code as-is, it showed floats, not rounded numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug of your Prolog. What are you using ? In SWI-Prolog, I get

```
?- sqrt_table(5,2,L).
L = [[5, 2.23606797749979], [4, 2.0], [3, 1.7320508075688772], [2, 1.4142135623730951]] 
.
```

quite reasonable, I think...

*edit* Now I understand your problem: you need to access the floating point number in the sublists... Here I use member to get on backtracking access to the computed list

```
2 ?- sqrt_table(5,2,L),member([_,R],L),format('~4f',R).
2.2361
L = [[5, 2.23606797749979], [4, 2.0], [3, 1.7320508075688772], [2, 1.4142135623730951]],
R = 2.23606797749979 ;
2.0000
L = [[5, 2.23606797749979], [4, 2.0], [3, 1.7320508075688772], [2, 1.4142135623730951]],
R = 2.0 ;
...
```

Comment: Can I do something like format("Result as follows: ~4f~n", [Result])

Comment: You mean where you insert into the list ? try `format(atom(A), '~4f', [X])` and put A into list. But I don't think it's a good idea...